# How to print an error when getting a wrong format input (datetime format) in a submit form in Django?

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

I'm building an application streaming object detection on web browser, the data (datetime, object info, etc.) is saved in mysql database, the app has a web page for filtering the data based on datetime, now it only works when the format is proper datetime format (e.g. 2019-07-24 12:00:00), if it's incorrect (e.g. 2019-07-123), web browser will return an error page.
[image]

search.html

```html
<input id="from_date" type="text" name="from_date" placeholder="From Date...">
<input id="to_date" type="text" name="to_date" placeholder="To Date...">
```

views.py

```py
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        from_date = request.GET.get('from_date')
        to_date = request.GET.get('to_date')

        "code to detect if from_date and to_date are incorrect formats???"
```

I want to know how can I detect that case then print an error in my web template.

Comment: Use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) with [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django provides [**`forms`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/), in which `DateTimeField` can handle datetime formatting issues.

Still, if you want to use your existing code, then you can do the following implementation:

```
import datetime

def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        from_date = request.GET.get('from_date')
        to_date = request.GET.get('to_date')
        input_formats = [
            '%y-%m-%d %H:%M',
            '%y-%m-%d',
         ]
         from_date_validated = None
         to_date_validated = None

         for format in input_formats:
            try:
                from_date_validated = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, format)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                continue
            try:
                to_date_validated = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, format)
            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                continue
         if not to_date_validated or not from_date_validated:
             return render(request, 'error_page.html', context={'to_date_validated': to_date_validated, 'from_date_validated': from_date_validated})
```

And update the template:

```
{% if not to_date_validated %}
    Please enter proper to date
{% else %}
   Please enter proper from date
{% endif %}
```